# Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. and "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" in tests

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package, babeljs

I have some settings for couple files babel and webpack, but can't find the problem

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/, // we do not need to transpile other libraries
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/react', 'es2015'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/proposal-class-properties']
                    },
                },
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            fs: false,
        },
        alias: {
            config$: './configs/app-config.js',
            react: './vendor/react-master',
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
            'bower_components',
            'shared',
            '/shared/vendor/modules',
        ],
    },
    target: 'node',
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv({
            path: './.env',
            safe: true,
            allowEmptyValues: true,
            systemvars: true,
            silent: true,
            defaults: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ inject: true, template: path.resolve('./public/index.html') }),
    ]
}
```

babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "useESModules": true,
        "regenerator": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "pinball",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "^29.4.2",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.57.3",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.12.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.19",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-config-ts-react-important-stuff": "^3.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "immer": "^9.0.19",
    "maplibre-gl": "^2.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "os": "^0.1.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.9",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "sass": "^1.58.0",
    "three": "^0.149.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env webpack",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@cfaester/enzyme-adapter-react-18": "^0.6.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-jest": "^29.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-cli": "^27.5.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "your-dependecy-package": {
      "axios": "1.2.6"
    }
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
}
```

How to make it work for tests, build including env file?
I tried to remove or add settings but everything leads to this error on the build.
Also setting up tests doesn't work with running tests.